# Numpad special keys are discarded - on my account only

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, numpad

On my laptop, **the numpad keys stopped working when NumLock is ON**.
So I can input all the digits, but when I enable NumLock, the keys do nothing at all (directions, home, end, pgup/down, even Enter does nothing).

This happens when working from a terminal, or from gedit, etc.
The "Keyboard Layout Chart" is showing that the keys I press are not received at all (when NumLock is ON).

The keys do work correctly when:

- I create a simple terminal ("xterm" command)
- I switch to one of the virtual terminals (Ctrl+Alt+F1)
- In my browser.
- I created a fresh user account, and logged in to it

I tried the usual things I found on the net:

- "xev" utility shows that the keys are recognized correctly (I receive KP_Home, KP_Left, etc)
- this is not related to "controlling mouse cursor with keypad" issue (I tried that option and I can fully enable/disable it in addition to my issue)

All that leads me to believe that **some X-related input/keyboard filtering/processing configuration is to blame here**, and that it's related to my account only.

**Where else can I look to check what's wrong?**

**Are there any other files/configurations/tools I can check?**

I had Ubuntu 15.10 when that happened (out of the blue, I didn't install/configure anything on that day), then I upgraded to 16.04 (hoping the issue would just go away). Reboots didn't help.